# Basic Current mirror using BJTS

Tags: bjt, current-mirror

[image]

Hi, I'm fairly new to BJTs and I've been trying to analyze the above basic current mirror to prove that $$I_{ref} = I $$ (aproximately), but have gotten nowhere. I have attached where I've gotten so far[image]

Comment: Think about the problem some more. The BJT has current gain, so the base current is NOT I(ref)/2. Start by trying to work out what would happen if you only had the left hand BJT.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, I'm not sure that's a good move in the analysis stage.  I'll write an answer.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri You're right, I'll delete the comment. He needs Ib for the analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Label the left-most transistor Q1 and the right-most Q2.

At the Q1 collector node, write a KCL equation (assume identical transistors):

$$I_{ref} = I_{C1} + I_{B1} + I_{B2} = I_{C1}\left(1 + \frac{2}{\beta}\right)$$

Thus

$$I_{C1} = \frac{I_{ref}}{1 + \frac{2}{\beta}}$$

and it follows that

$$I_{B2} =  I_{B1} = \frac{I_{ref}}{\beta + 2}$$

thus (ignoring the Early effect)

$$I_{C2} = \beta I_{B2} = I_{ref}\frac{\beta}{\beta + 2}$$

It's straightforward from here to include the [Early effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_effect) and then see why, e.g., the [Wilson current mirror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson_current_mirror) is superior